# Gparted unmount botton is off

Tags: gparted

installed Ubuntu 21.04 but then it got broke and i installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside 21.04 ant then moved all my data from 21.04 to 20.04 ant then removed 21.04 by Gparted. now i just want to expand my 20.04 main partition by unallocated space which used to be 21.04 place. the problem is that i cant do it because i have to unmount the partition from a live disk. when i open Gparted to resize the partition, i cant unmount it because it seems it already happend and so i cant expand my partition? please help me.

[image: 1]

[image]

Comment: You don't have to unmount any partition ina live session. By default no partition is mounted in a live session therefore there's nothing to unmount, reason why that function is grayed out. Please read the answer (and comment) to understand what to do. It has nothing to do with what you think it is and made into this question's title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't expand sda5, not because of its mounting status, but because there is a tiny sda4 fat32 partition in front of it. You must do something with that sda4 partition in order to expand sda5. Delete it or move it.

I suggest making sure you have solid backups before performing any partition operations.

Comment: I suggest deleting `sda4`. Then they must move `sda5` all the way to the left and only then resize (expand).

Comment: okay thank you guys all. it did help me to expand my sda5. now there is two other problem i have left which i would be happy if you could guide me please.

1. grub still shows everytime i start the system and the 21.04 is still an option which i don't want it to show.

2. the booting time is so long and ubuntu would load so slower than 21.04 and it makes me worried.